# Pythonic way of calling a method with large number of arguments inside another method

Tags: python

I am a novice to python and wondering how an experienced coder will approach the following problem.

I have a method called `foo` with several arguments. I need to call the method inside another method, `bar`. Is there a way (avoiding the class attribute usage), in which I can avoid passing the same arguments for the method 'foo' into the method 'bar'?

```
class Class:

    def __init__(self, attr1):
        self.attr1 = attr1

    def foo(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):

        return arg1*arg2*arg3

    def bar(self, arg1,arg2, arg3, arg4):

        return arg4*self.foo(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

I have to call the `bar` method from other classes too, and I was wondering if there is an elegant solution to this which can use fewer arguments.

Comment: Splat notation would work but you'd make arg4 keyword-only then

Comment: @MadPhysicist, With 'splat notation' are you inferring to *args and **kwargs? If not, can you please point me to any reading materials/links?

Comment: Splat is *args and splatty-splat is **kwargs in a notation suggested by @wim that I happen to like

Comment: Also, please fix your indentation.

Comment: Thank you. 

I have fixed the indentation.

Comment: It's worth noting that the best solution might depend on what the functions are actually doing.  The example you gave can certainly be done with only a single function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do here really depends on the actual purpose of your functions. There is no way to avoid passing arguments as such, but there are ways to make the code shorter and more legible under the right conditions.

I would first determine if `foo` works for arbitrary inputs or not. If the arguments are really distinct and serve different purposes, I would leave it as-is and accept that the argument list is going to be long. If, on the other hand, some arguments are not really distinct and can be treated as a sequence, I would make that explicit using splat notation. The key is not so much to modify the inputs as to rewrite `foo` itself to handle arbitrary inputs:

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

def foo(*args):
     return reduce(mul, args)
```

Of course, some of the arguments might be distinct and important on their own, in which case you can mix and match:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, *args):
     return arg2 * (arg1 + reduce(mul, args))
```

Now you can decide what to do with `bar`. The result will depend on what you did with `foo` as well as the overall purpose of `bar` itself.

If `bar`'s only major dependency is `foo`, it can accept `foo`'s arguments directly. One thing I would highly recommend is moving the non-`foo` arguments (`arg4` in your example) to the front of the argument list. Even if you decided that `foo` requires umpteen distinct named arguments, you can still do:

```
def bar(arg4, *args, **kwargs):
    return arg4 * foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

Just remember to document very clearly. Make sure there is a note along the lines of "all remaining arguments are passed directly to `foo`".

A more involved case could be where `bar` either delegates to many complex functions, or just has a large number of arguments itself. In this case, I would stick `foo`'s argument list into two separate variables, for the positional and keyword arguments. This is very common in matplotlib, where something like an annotation object needs to have text properties, arrow properties, different transforms, etc:

```
def bar(arg4, foo_args=None, foo_kwargs=None):
     if foo_args is None:
         foo_args = ()
     if foo_kwargs is None:
         foo_kwargs = {}
     return arg4 * foo(*foo_args, **foo_kwargs)
```

The reason we have to do `foo_kwargs=None` is that default arguments are persistent and accessible. If you were to modify that argument outside the function, `foo` would be called with a non-empty dictionary by default. It is a common rookie mistake to make default arguments that are empty containers, only to realize that they aren't empty once your function has run. We get around this by using an immutable sentinel value like `None`, which lets us know when to create a new, empty container from scratch. Notice that `foo_args=None` is not strictly necessary, since an empty tuple will always stay empty. I just felt that it would be more consistent as shown.

I have written all the examples in function notation, but if course the ideas are completely transferrable to methods.

Answer (score 1):

Without usage of class attributes/global variables, I think you have to just pass on the arguments. However you could write

```
class Class:

    def __init__(self, attr1):
         self.attr1 = attr1

     def foo(self, *args):
         # Your logic here/if this is the usage use reduce
         return args[0]*args[1]*args[2]

    def bar(self, *args):
        return args[3]*self.foo(*args[:3])
```

As you can see this code sacrifices on the readability of the code. PEP8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to clarify.

Or you could also do:

```
class Class:

    def __init__(self, attr1):
         self.attr1 = attr1

     def foo(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
         # Your logic here/if this is the usage use reduce
         return arg1*arg2*arg3

    def bar(self, *args):
        return args[3]*self.foo(*args[:3])
```

Here the `*`-operator iterates over the array given and supplies its elements to the called function.

Comment: You need to unpack `args[:3]` when you call `foo` in the first example (second one looks right)

Comment: Thanks for noting that one out @MadPhysicist ! Now it should be somewhat okay

Comment: ```reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, args)``` works well if you have an arbitrary number of arguments

Comment: Yes that's the truth, however functools mul is much faster as the bytecoin is optimized. `from functools import mul; reduce(mul, args)`